# How can I check the duration after I click the button

Tags: android, handler, runnable, ontouchlistener, android-timer

I'm new to `Java` and `Android`, I would like to set up a time counter in my `ACTION_UP` event and cancel the timer while I do the other events. How can I basically set up a timer for that and stop and reset the timer for other event?

Comment: Do you want to get just start and end time difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Timer start time.**

Set this in start timer click event.

```
Date startDate = new Date();
long startTime = 0;
startTime = startDate.getTime();
```

Store startTime in Global Variable so you can use that variable later.

**Timer end time.**

Set this in stop timer click event.

```
Date endDate = new Date();
long endTime = 0;
endTime = endDate.getTime();
```

Now get **time difference** in **millisecond**.

```
long timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
```

Comment: Actually your way works for me! Thanks for assisting!

Answer (score 2):

For the `CountDownTimer` Here I've started 30 seconds of time ticker like

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
TextView tvTicker = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTicker);

public void startClicked(View view) { //When button start is clicked

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tvTicker.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
//Do some stuff here for saving the duration to a variable or anything else as your requirements
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tvTicker.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

**Method Description**

```
CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
```

`millisInFuture` = *Time in milliseconds*

`countDownInterval` = *Interval in millisecond*

Now you can use these methods For other kind of operation.

```
countDownTimer.cancel(); //Cancel the countdown.
countDownTimer.onFinish() //Callback fired when the time is up.
countDownTimer.onTick(long millisUntilFinished); //Callback fired on regular `interval. millisUntilFinished is The amount of time until finished.`
```

Comment: Your solution works, thanks a lot! You just saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean touch;
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch = true;
                // Code for Timer
                break;
        }
    return true;
    }
```

You have to write the handler inside this code and reset the handler on other events.
code for handler

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Your Task                   
        }
    }, TIME);
```